# Have Jenkins build NOT be triggered when doing git push

Tags: git, jenkins

I couldn't find whether this was asked so I'll give it a shot. I have a Git configuration set up with Jenkins so that when I use `git push`, it will trigger a Jenkins build for that branch. However, is there some type of flag or something for the `git push` where I don't want to trigger the Jenkins build ***for that specific push***? That way, I could push changes, but I wouldn't have to go to Jenkins and cancel the build if I don't desire to schedule a build.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are pushing to GitHub, the [usual setting involve a webhook](https://oncomputingwell.princeton.edu/2018/01/triggering-a-jenkins-build-every-time-changes-are-pushed-to-a-git-branch-on-github/), which means it cannot be easily customized.

The other option would be to use a GitHub Action like [`trigger-jenkins-job`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/trigger-jenkins-job).
It also does not allow any parameter, but you could take a look at how this action is done in [`appleboy/jenkins-action`](https://github.com/appleboy/jenkins-action) (based on [`appleboy/drone-jenkins`](https://github.com/appleboy/drone-jenkins)), and make your own action with the required added feature.